# R Plot in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I quite a few data sets that I would like to plot using a for loop.
I make a list using

```
dflist <- c('Set1', 'Set2','Set3', 'Set4')
```

Then I try to do:

```
for (i in dflist) {
   plot(i$var1,i$var2)
}
```

Which does not work.
Could anyone sort me out here?

Comment: i$var1 throws an exception. You need a better reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *dflist<-list(set1,set2)* otherwise you get a list of individual var1 and var2 vectors in dflist

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get` for this, which 'gets' the object associated with the supplied name.

```
# two data frames
a = data.frame(x=1:10,y=sqrt(1:10)); b=data.frame(x=1:10,y=exp(1:10))

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
dfs = c('a', 'b')
for (i in dfs){
    plot(get(i)$x, get(i)$y, type='o')
}
```

Or `apply` to avoid a loop, applying a custom function to each item in the list.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
dflist = list(a,b)
lapply(X=dflist, FUN = function(x) plot(x$x, x$y, type='o')
```